# How to create higher priority to TYPO3 Extbase FE Plugin code?

Tags: authentication, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, hybridauth

I am about to write an own social media login extension for TYPO3 7 (LTS).
The connection to FE users is set up and everything seems to work in general.
The extension offers a **FE plugin** that has the typical login buttons.

My problem is now, the login code runs to late (I guess in the FE plugin environment). Every other website parts (template extension etc.) that are related to the login state still say the user is logged out. Only if you reload the page everything works.

So where and how can I initialize a function that can evaluate Extbase form data and do something like

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = 0;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->is_permanent = 0;
$info = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
$user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $username);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = true;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('dummy', TRUE);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
```

before any other extension comes and check for the login state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do, is look into the Authentication Service layer of TYPO3 - that is the part that authenticates and create a session for both frontend and backend. The docs are full with great descriptions

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Typo3ServicesReference/7.6/Developer/NewServiceType/Index.html

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Typo3ServicesReference/7.6/Authentication/Index.html

And look at a extension like `social_auth`

https://github.com/kalypso63/social_auth

for reference

Comment: Looks great to me. But how can I initialize the auth process by my FE plugin form? Do I need to call the `tx_felogin_pi1` somehow or put in some special post variables / values?

Comment: It's done automatically because you register your service ext_localconf.php

https://github.com/kalypso63/social_auth/blob/master/ext_localconf.php#L33

This call, for example, this method https://github.com/kalypso63/social_auth/blob/master/Classes/Service/SocialAuthenticationService.php#L167 at the authentication process, which is really early in the process of a request

Comment: As long as I don't use the standard `tx_felogin_pi1` form the service called functions `getUser` and `authUser` (which I adapted to my project) will never be touched in any page call. So I need something like a login form without username/password. But has to be in there?

Comment: okay I've got it my self. I just copied the hidden inputs of the regular login. Now I can start the hook party. Thanks once again :)